# How to initiate route discovery before data transmission in multihop network?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am studying X-MAC in multihop sensor network. I am using AODV as a routing protocol. During run time, at the beginning, I can see that the sensor node starts sending preambles before any route discovery. So, until any route is established these preambles are sent for nothing.
I also studied the same network with csma/ca, in which the route is established first and then the node initiate transmission.

As per suggestions given in OmNET++ group, I tried the following, but it did not resolve the issue.

**.useHelloMessages = true

Would anyone please advice how to configure X-MAC so that when the simulation starts, a node will first establish a route and then it will send preambles for data communication?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of the simulation, there are no routes. So when one of the nodes have some data to send (they contain a TCP app that generates a TCP packet, for example), the AODV initiates route discovery to the destination of the data (the TCP packet).
Aodv does this route discovery by sending an Aodv route request message (AodvRreq). The message indicates that the node wants to discover a route to the destination of the data.

Aodv is implemented as an app in INET, and it sends its route request (and other) messages encapsulated in UDP packets.

The packets (aodv or data) go down the protocol stack to the XMAC for transmission.

So, from the point of view of the XMAC, the Aodv route request message (which is triggered by the node wanting to send TCP data) is itself treated as data (since it uses UDP). In order to send data, the XMAC first sends preambles.

(Answer edited for more details)

Comment: Would you please elaborate the answer? I could not understand it clearly. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. But I observed that at the beginning, for a node,  when the preamble duration is over, that node sends data and that gets lost as no route is discovered yet. I wanted to know how to configure X-MAC or AODV so that a node will send RREQ first to discover a route and then will send preambles.

Comment: The node shouldn't send any data if there are no routes. Are you sure there are no routes? What I mean is...are static routes and netmask routes turned off?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not clear about your question. But I studied your answer. If X-MAC considers RREQ as data and for that it sends preambles, would you please advise how to configure so that X-MAC will not treat route discovery messages as data? As I mentioned in the question, with CSMA, the node starts with sending RREQ, then when route is established, it sends data. With X-MAC how i can do the same? Many thanks.

Comment: I think X-MAC inherently works like this - it sends preambles before any transmission. Is it a requirement for you to use X-MAC, or can you consider something else? What I mean is, as you said, CSMA doesn't send preambles. There is also L-MAC, which is a manet routing protocol like X-MAC, but it works with TDMA, so it doesn't send preambles.

Comment: Yes, I have to use X-MAC. So do you think there is no way to configure X-MAC, so it won't treat RREQ messages as data?

Comment: Sorry, in my previous answer I meant manet MAC protocol, not manet routing protocol when talking about XMAC and LMAC.

Comment: As far as I know, the preambles can't be turned off, so no.